# Broken symlinks and a mysterious (deleted)

Tags: linux, bash, symlink, procfs

I've been doing stuff with the proc filesystem on linux, and I've come across some behavior I'd like to have clarified.

Each process in `/proc` has a symlink to it's executable file, `/proc/{pid}/exe`. If a process continues to run after it's executable has been deleted, reading this symlink will return the path to the executable, with `(deleted)` appended to the end.

Running this command you may even see a few on your system:

```
grep '(deleted)' <(for dir in $(ls /proc | grep -E '^[0-9]+'); do echo "$dir $(readlink /proc/$dir/exe)"; done)
```

I tried recreating this behavior with some simple bash commands:

```
>>> echo "temporary file" >> tmpfile.test
>>> ln -s tmpfile.test tmpfile.link
>>> rm tmpfile.test
>>> readlink tmpfile.link
tmpfile.test
```

There is no `(deleted)` appended to the name! Trying a `cat tmpfile.link` confirms that the link is broken (`cat: tmpfile.link: No such file or directory`).

However, the other day this same test did result in a `(deleted)` being appended to the output of readlink. What gives?

Here is what I would like to know:

- Is there a sequences of events that guarantees `(deleted)` will be
  appended to the name?
- Why does `/proc/{pid}/exe` show `(deleted)` for removed executables?
- How can I get the name of an executable through `/proc/{pid}/exe`
  without any appended `(deleted)` and guarantee that the original
  executable wasn't just named `some_executable (deleted)`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not `readlink`, but Linux changes the symlink to point to `<filename> (deleted)`, i.e., `(deleted)` gets appended to the target of the link.

Comment: Not quite the answer I'm looking for, but it set me off in the right direction.

Answer (score 5):

FWIW, the special `<filename> (deleted)` behavior is implemented in the Linux kernel function `d_path()` here: https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.1.13/source/fs/dcache.c#L3080.

The source comments (in the snippet below) suggest the special behavior only applies to names (paths) generated on-the-fly for some 'synthetic filesystems' (e.g. `procfs`) and 'psuedo inodes'.

```
/**
 * d_path - return the path of a dentry
 * @path: path to report
 * @buf: buffer to return value in
 * @buflen: buffer length
 *
 * Convert a dentry into an ASCII path name. If the entry has been deleted
 * the string " (deleted)" is appended. Note that this is ambiguous.
 *
 * Returns a pointer into the buffer or an error code if the path was
 * too long. Note: Callers should use the returned pointer, not the passed
 * in buffer, to use the name! The implementation often starts at an offset
 * into the buffer, and may leave 0 bytes at the start.
 *
 * "buflen" should be positive.
 */
char *d_path(const struct path *path, char *buf, int buflen)
{
    char *res = buf + buflen;
    struct path root;
    int error;

    /*
     * We have various synthetic filesystems that never get mounted.  On
     * these filesystems dentries are never used for lookup purposes, and
     * thus don't need to be hashed.  They also don't need a name until a
     * user wants to identify the object in /proc/pid/fd/.  The little hack
     * below allows us to generate a name for these objects on demand:
     *
     * Some pseudo inodes are mountable.  When they are mounted
     * path->dentry == path->mnt->mnt_root.  In that case don't call d_dname
     * and instead have d_path return the mounted path.
     */
    if (path->dentry->d_op && path->dentry->d_op->d_dname &&
        (!IS_ROOT(path->dentry) || path->dentry != path->mnt->mnt_root))
        return path->dentry->d_op->d_dname(path->dentry, buf, buflen);

    rcu_read_lock();
    get_fs_root_rcu(current->fs, &root);
    error = path_with_deleted(path, &root, &res, &buflen);
    rcu_read_unlock();

    if (error < 0)
        res = ERR_PTR(error);
    return res;
}
```