# Perf report: shared object names showing up as `(deleted)` in docker

Tags: c++, swift, docker, perf, ldd

I profiled two binaries that run the same logical computation, one written in Swift the other in C++. The code is very simple, just does some math computation in a loop. I am using the [Swift docker image](https://hub.docker.com/_/swift/) running with `--privileged`.

Now, I know that the system libraries `libm.so` and `libc.so` are stripped in the docker instance, so symbolification might not be great, but in this case the shared objects are showing up as `(deleted)` for the C++ code, but not for the Swift code.

The C++ code was compiled with `-g -O3 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -std=c++20 -fwrapv -fno-omit-frame-pointer -mno-omit-leaf-frame-pointer`. I recorded using `perf record -g`, and this is the output of `perf report -g 'graph,1.0,caller`.

```
Samples: 187K of event 'cpu-clock:pppH', Event count (approx.): 46774250000                                                                                    
  Children      Self  Command  Shared Object      Symbol                                                                                                       
+  100.00%     0.00%  profile  profile            [.] _start
+  100.00%     0.00%  profile   (deleted)         [.] 0x0000ffff88e274cc
+  100.00%     0.00%  profile   (deleted)         [.] 0x0000ffff88e273fc
+  100.00%     0.00%  profile  profile            [.] main
+   76.43%     8.62%  profile  profile            [.] synthetic
+   32.22%     2.66%  profile  profile            [.] siam100_integrand
+   23.32%     0.00%  profile   (deleted)         [.] 0x0000ffff88fe54e4
+   23.32%    23.32%  profile   (deleted)         [.] 0x00000000000354e4
+   19.79%     0.00%  profile   (deleted)         [.] 0x0000ffff88fe54d8
+   19.79%    19.79%  profile   (deleted)         [.] 0x00000000000354d8
+   17.17%     0.00%  profile   (deleted)         [.] 0x0000ffff88fe88f0
+   17.17%    17.17%  profile   (deleted)         [.] 0x00000000000388f0
+    8.16%     8.16%  profile   (deleted)         [.] 0x00000000000387f4
+    8.16%     0.00%  profile   (deleted)         [.] 0x0000ffff88fe87f4
+    4.92%     4.92%  profile   (deleted)         [.] 0x00000000000354b4
+    4.92%     0.00%  profile   (deleted)         [.] 0x0000ffff88fe54b4
+    3.78%     3.78%  profile  profile            [.] cos@plt
+    2.22%     2.22%  profile  profile            [.] log@plt
```

`profile` is the name of the binary. The deleted shared object entries should be mostly `libm.so`, `libc.so`, and `kernel.kallsyms`. But, on stepping into the debugger I cannot set breakpoints at the addresses shown in the perf report output: `Cannot access memory at address 0xffff88fe54e4` for example.

Here is the same report for the binary built using swift.

```
Samples: 54K of event 'cpu-clock:pppH', Event count (approx.): 13628000000                                                                                     
  Children      Self  Command  Shared Object          Symbol                                                                                                   
+   99.97%     0.00%  Run      Run                    [.] _start
+   99.97%     0.00%  Run      libc.so.6              [.] __libc_start_main@@GLIBC_2.34
+   99.97%     0.00%  Run      libc.so.6              [.] __libc_start_call_main
+   99.97%     0.00%  Run      Run                    [.] Run_main
+   43.46%    43.46%  Run      libm.so.6              [.] log@@GLIBC_2.29
+   39.18%     7.92%  Run      Run                    [.] $s7BMDemos9synthetic__9iterCountS2d_SdSitF
+   31.27%    31.26%  Run      libm.so.6              [.] __cos
+    8.41%     8.41%  Run      libm.so.6              [.] __math_invalid
+    5.97%     5.97%  Run      Run                    [.] log@plt
+    2.94%     2.94%  Run      Run                    [.] cos@plt
```

Another difference between the binaries is that the C++ one jumps directly to `log` via the procedure linkage table, while the Swift one has to perform some kind of `dlsym` looking lookup. This I found out when stepping through with the debugger asm line at at time.

So, I have the following questions.

1. What are the possible causes for this difference between the two reports?
2. If possible, can the reporting for the C++ code be improved?

## Appendix

### `ldd -v` on the C++ binary

```
linux-vdso.so.1 (0x0000ffff9a112000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x0000ffff99e90000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x0000ffff99df0000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x0000ffff99c40000)
    /lib/ld-linux-aarch64.so.1 (0x0000ffff9a0d9000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x0000ffff99c10000)

    Version information:
    ./profile:
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.34) => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.17) => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
        libm.so.6 (GLIBC_2.29) => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6
        libm.so.6 (GLIBC_2.17) => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6
        libstdc++.so.6 (GLIBCXX_3.4.9) => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
        libstdc++.so.6 (GLIBCXX_3.4.11) => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
        libstdc++.so.6 (GLIBCXX_3.4) => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
    /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6:
        ld-linux-aarch64.so.1 (GLIBC_2.17) => /lib/ld-linux-aarch64.so.1
        libm.so.6 (GLIBC_2.17) => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.33) => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.25) => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.18) => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.32) => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.17) => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.34) => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
        libgcc_s.so.1 (GCC_4.2.0) => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
        libgcc_s.so.1 (GCC_3.3) => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
        libgcc_s.so.1 (GCC_3.0) => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
        libgcc_s.so.1 (GCC_4.5.0) => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
    /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6:
        ld-linux-aarch64.so.1 (GLIBC_2.17) => /lib/ld-linux-aarch64.so.1
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_PRIVATE) => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.17) => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
    /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6:
        ld-linux-aarch64.so.1 (GLIBC_PRIVATE) => /lib/ld-linux-aarch64.so.1
        ld-linux-aarch64.so.1 (GLIBC_2.17) => /lib/ld-linux-aarch64.so.1
    /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1:
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.35) => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.34) => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.17) => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
```

### `ldd -v` on the Swift binary

```
linux-vdso.so.1 (0x0000ffff8b009000)
    libswiftCore.so => /usr/lib/swift/linux/libswiftCore.so (0x0000ffff8a960000)
    libswift_Concurrency.so => /usr/lib/swift/linux/libswift_Concurrency.so (0x0000ffff8a8e0000)
    libswift_StringProcessing.so => /usr/lib/swift/linux/libswift_StringProcessing.so (0x0000ffff8a800000)
    libswift_RegexParser.so => /usr/lib/swift/linux/libswift_RegexParser.so (0x0000ffff8a6e0000)
    libswiftGlibc.so => /usr/lib/swift/linux/libswiftGlibc.so (0x0000ffff8a6b0000)
    libBlocksRuntime.so => /usr/lib/swift/linux/libBlocksRuntime.so (0x0000ffff8a690000)
    libdispatch.so => /usr/lib/swift/linux/libdispatch.so (0x0000ffff8a610000)
    libswiftDispatch.so => /usr/lib/swift/linux/libswiftDispatch.so (0x0000ffff8a5c0000)
    libFoundation.so => /usr/lib/swift/linux/libFoundation.so (0x0000ffff89d40000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x0000ffff89ca0000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x0000ffff89af0000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x0000ffff898c0000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x0000ffff89890000)
    /lib/ld-linux-aarch64.so.1 (0x0000ffff8afd0000)
    libicuucswift.so.65 => /usr/lib/swift/linux/libicuucswift.so.65 (0x0000ffff89680000)
    libicui18nswift.so.65 => /usr/lib/swift/linux/libicui18nswift.so.65 (0x0000ffff89360000)
    libicudataswift.so.65 => /usr/lib/swift/linux/libicudataswift.so.65 (0x0000ffff878a0000)

    Version information:
    .build/release/Run:
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.17) => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.34) => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
        libm.so.6 (GLIBC_2.17) => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6
        libm.so.6 (GLIBC_2.29) => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6
    /usr/lib/swift/linux/libswiftCore.so:
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.17) => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.34) => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.32) => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.33) => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
        libm.so.6 (GLIBC_2.17) => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6
        libm.so.6 (GLIBC_2.29) => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6
        libm.so.6 (GLIBC_2.27) => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6
        libgcc_s.so.1 (GCC_3.0) => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
        libgcc_s.so.1 (GCC_3.3) => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
        libstdc++.so.6 (GLIBCXX_3.4.17) => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
        libstdc++.so.6 (CXXABI_1.3.11) => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
        libstdc++.so.6 (GLIBCXX_3.4.21) => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
        libstdc++.so.6 (GLIBCXX_3.4) => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
        libstdc++.so.6 (GLIBCXX_3.4.29) => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
        libstdc++.so.6 (GLIBCXX_3.4.18) => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
        libstdc++.so.6 (GLIBCXX_3.4.14) => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
        libstdc++.so.6 (CXXABI_1.3) => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
        ld-linux-aarch64.so.1 (GLIBC_2.17) => /lib/ld-linux-aarch64.so.1
    /usr/lib/swift/linux/libswift_Concurrency.so:
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.17) => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.34) => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.32) => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
        libstdc++.so.6 (GLIBCXX_3.4.11) => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
        libstdc++.so.6 (GLIBCXX_3.4) => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
        libstdc++.so.6 (CXXABI_1.3) => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
        libstdc++.so.6 (GLIBCXX_3.4.21) => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
        libstdc++.so.6 (GLIBCXX_3.4.18) => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
        libstdc++.so.6 (GLIBCXX_3.4.29) => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
        ld-linux-aarch64.so.1 (GLIBC_2.17) => /lib/ld-linux-aarch64.so.1
    /usr/lib/swift/linux/libswift_StringProcessing.so:
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.17) => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
        ld-linux-aarch64.so.1 (GLIBC_2.17) => /lib/ld-linux-aarch64.so.1
    /usr/lib/swift/linux/libswift_RegexParser.so:
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.17) => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
        ld-linux-aarch64.so.1 (GLIBC_2.17) => /lib/ld-linux-aarch64.so.1
    /usr/lib/swift/linux/libswiftGlibc.so:
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.17) => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.34) => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
        ld-linux-aarch64.so.1 (GLIBC_2.17) => /lib/ld-linux-aarch64.so.1
        libm.so.6 (GLIBC_2.17) => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6
        libm.so.6 (GLIBC_2.27) => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6
        libm.so.6 (GLIBC_2.35) => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6
    /usr/lib/swift/linux/libBlocksRuntime.so:
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.17) => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
    /usr/lib/swift/linux/libdispatch.so:
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.33) => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.32) => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.34) => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.17) => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
    /usr/lib/swift/linux/libswiftDispatch.so:
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.17) => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
        ld-linux-aarch64.so.1 (GLIBC_2.17) => /lib/ld-linux-aarch64.so.1
    /usr/lib/swift/linux/libFoundation.so:
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.17) => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.34) => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.33) => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
        libm.so.6 (GLIBC_2.35) => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6
        libm.so.6 (GLIBC_2.29) => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6
        libm.so.6 (GLIBC_2.17) => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6
        libgcc_s.so.1 (GCC_3.0) => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
        libgcc_s.so.1 (GCC_3.3.1) => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
        ld-linux-aarch64.so.1 (GLIBC_2.17) => /lib/ld-linux-aarch64.so.1
    /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6:
        ld-linux-aarch64.so.1 (GLIBC_2.17) => /lib/ld-linux-aarch64.so.1
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_PRIVATE) => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.17) => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
    /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6:
        ld-linux-aarch64.so.1 (GLIBC_PRIVATE) => /lib/ld-linux-aarch64.so.1
        ld-linux-aarch64.so.1 (GLIBC_2.17) => /lib/ld-linux-aarch64.so.1
    /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6:
        ld-linux-aarch64.so.1 (GLIBC_2.17) => /lib/ld-linux-aarch64.so.1
        libm.so.6 (GLIBC_2.17) => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.33) => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.25) => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.18) => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.32) => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.17) => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.34) => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
        libgcc_s.so.1 (GCC_4.2.0) => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
        libgcc_s.so.1 (GCC_3.3) => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
        libgcc_s.so.1 (GCC_3.0) => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
        libgcc_s.so.1 (GCC_4.5.0) => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
    /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1:
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.35) => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.34) => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.17) => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
    /usr/lib/swift/linux/libicuucswift.so.65:
        libgcc_s.so.1 (GCC_3.0) => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
        libm.so.6 (GLIBC_2.29) => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6
        libm.so.6 (GLIBC_2.17) => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6
        libstdc++.so.6 (GLIBCXX_3.4.11) => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
        libstdc++.so.6 (CXXABI_1.3) => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
        libstdc++.so.6 (GLIBCXX_3.4.30) => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
        libstdc++.so.6 (GLIBCXX_3.4) => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.34) => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.33) => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.17) => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
    /usr/lib/swift/linux/libicui18nswift.so.65:
        libgcc_s.so.1 (GCC_3.0) => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
        libstdc++.so.6 (CXXABI_1.3) => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
        libstdc++.so.6 (GLIBCXX_3.4) => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
        libm.so.6 (GLIBC_2.29) => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6
        libm.so.6 (GLIBC_2.17) => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.17) => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70660806/why-perf-report-does-not-show-function-names-in-the-second-run-when-used-in-d/75558604#75558604 - something to do with symlinks that are deleted before perf can resolve them.  (I am no expert: the link is all I know)

Answer (score 1):

## Workaround

For some reason `perf report` tries to look for the executable with  `(deleted)` appended to it. Creating a copy of the profiled executable with the name `<executable name> (deleted)` ends up working just fine.

A better alternative would be to create a symbolic link to the binary so that recompilations do not result in the alias becoming outdated.

Comment: Symlinks like `/proc/<PID>/exe`, `/proc/<PID>/fd/3`, and `/proc/<PID>/map_files/*` will show the link-name as `/foo/bar (deleted)` if the orig file doesn't exist. For example `/dev/shm/.org.chromium.Chromium.bsbRnb (deleted)` shows up in my `lsof` (ls open files) output. This is a name invented by the kernel when user-space makes a `readlink` system call on those files, which is why programs like `ls -l` also show that.  The kernel I guess remembers the original path used for `open`.  (Opening those special files for read or write still works to get access to the now-anonymous file / inode.)